# How to Pass data between 2 Dialogs in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I need to pass an Array from one Dialog to another in Qt.

I have 6 Lineedits from which I collect numbers to store in my Array.
I want to transfer USERZAHLEN[] from SecDialog to ThirdDialog.
I've tried many solutions but none of them seem to work.

```
SecDialog.cpp 
@
void SecDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int Zahl1 = ui->lineEdit_Zahl1->text().toInt();
    int Zahl2 = ui->lineEdit_Zahl2->text().toInt();
    int Zahl3 = ui->lineEdit_Zahl3->text().toInt();
    int Zahl4 = ui->lineEdit_Zahl4->text().toInt();
    int Zahl5 = ui->lineEdit_Zahl5->text().toInt();
    int Zahl6 = ui->lineEdit_Zahl6->text().toInt();

    int Userzahlen[] = {Zahl1, Zahl2, Zahl3, Zahl4, Zahl5, Zahl6};

    hide();
    thirddialog = new ThirdDialog(this);
    thirddialog->show();
}

SecDialog.h

namespace Ui {
class SecDialog;
}

class SecDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int Zahl1, Zahl2, Zahl3, Zahl4, Zahl5, Zahl6;  
    explicit SecDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SecDialog();



private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::SecDialog *ui;
    ThirdDialog *thirddialog;
};

#endif // SECDIALOG_H
@
```

I'm mainly using Qt-Creator.

Comment: You probably want to use signals and slots for this.

Comment: Off-topic: Try to get rid of German identifiers and used to English ones right from the start. There *will* be some time when you need to share code with non-germanophones (and if only here on SO). While not relevant here, in general not understanding what variables are intended for will make it much harder to read the code for those trying to help you...

Comment: Unrelated: When you find yourself with a contiguous series if numbered variables, `Zahl1`, `Zahl2`, etc... consider using an array.

Comment: ***I've tried many solutions but none of them seem to work*** It would help if you showed your attempt.

Comment: Yes but I'm struggling with where I should add Signals and Slots? :/

Comment: You can initialize the array mentioned by @user4581301 directly: `int userNumbers[] = { n1.get(), n2.get(), n3.get() };`

Comment: ***Yes but I'm struggling with where I should add Signals and Slots*** You signal from the dialog that sends data. You put slots on the dialog that needs to receive the data.

Comment: @drescherjm how do i do that?

Comment: Producing a new dialog all the time might result in a memory leak: QT is designed to clean them up automatically, but does so when the parent is destroyed. And you'll be adding more and more children as long as the application runs...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks i will change that :)

Comment: With that said if you are always creating a new instance of `ThirdDialog` in `on_pushButton_clicked` this seems to be more of a direct initialization of variables in ThirdDialog.

Comment: @dreschejm What should i do then?

Comment: I personally would rather consider creating 1st, 2nd and 3rd dialog only once and just show/hide the ones you need. Perhaps much better: there's a [QStackedLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html); you might have just one single dialog (containing the array as member) and just switch between the different stack views on need.

Comment: ***What should i do then?*** If you move to creating the dialogs 1 time use signals and slots. If you keep recreating the `ThirdDialog` initialize variables in `ThirdDialog` after you construct it.

Comment: Remember that since you did not show your code that attempts to solve the problem it is difficult to help you fix a bug in your implementation of this. We can give you direction on what to do but we are not really supposed to write your program for you.

Comment: @racki, It sounds like you should take a step back and understand Signals and Slots. They are fundamental to using Qt effectively.  Try reading [this introduction from the Qt Help pages](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).